# Problem with importing Numpy I delete numpy but when I try run program It says That I still have

Tags: python, numpy

Problem with importing Numpy, I delete numpy but when I try run program It says That I still have it, I tryed different versions but its not working anyway
Exception has occurred: ImportError

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

```
https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html
```

Please note and check the following:

- The Python version is: Python3.8 from "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe"
- The NumPy version is: "1.19.2"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: DLL load failed while importing _multiarray_umath: Nie można odnaleźć określonego modułu.
File "C:\Users\kamil\Desktop\m.py", line 1, in 
import numpy as np

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I delete the whole anaconda tools and install the only python, and change the chosen python tool in Visual studio. Because it was using anaconda instead of just python.